# About the riemann's hypothesis .

Tags: reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

Robin's inequality and Lagarius's inequality (forgive spelling) are two simpler statements that are equivalent to Riemann's hypothesis  ;are there any others?

Comment: you may want consult on mathoverflow

Comment: If 2($\phi(n)$) < ($\pi(n)$) ($\pi(ln(n))$) and n > 5041 then n is a counterexample to Riemann's Hypothesis. Is this a valid inequality for this hypothesis?